# Вывод дочерних групп в категориях

Tags: python, django, view, django-model, model

есть 2 модели.

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название категории')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, verbose_name='URL категории', blank=True)

class Groups(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название группы')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, verbose_name='URL группы', blank=True)
    category = TreeForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='groups', default='', verbose_name='Категория')
```

в views.py

```
class PostByGroupListView(ListView):
    model = Groups
    template_name = 'module/groups/post_group_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'groups'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['groups'] = Groups.objects.all().filter(groups__slug=self.group.slug)
        return context
```

Получается все группы привязаны к определенной категории.

1. Категория 1

   - Группа 1.1
   - Группа 1.2
   - Группа 1.3
   - Группа 1.4
2. Категория 2

   - Группа 2.1
   - Группа 2.2

Если захожу в на страницу с категориями то все дочерние группы данной категории отображаются как и должны.
Как сделать что бы если я нахожусь в любой и групп, что бы остальные дочерние группы данной категории тоже отображались